# PHP TCPDF and QR Code, cannot make the QR code bigger

Tags: php, tcpdf

I'm creating a PDF file from a source file that is  119.88 x 50.058 mm. However, when i place a QR code, I cannot make it bigger whether i specify it with size 50 or 500, no different. What do i need to do to make the QR code bigger?

Here is my code

```
$pdf = new FPDI('L', 'mm', array('119.888','50.038'));
$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->AddPage();
$page = $pdf->setSourceFile('aw_print.PDF');


$page = $pdf->ImportPage(1, 'TrimBox');
$pdf->useTemplate($page, 0, 0);


$x = 10;
$y = 10;

$style = array(
    'border' => 1,
    'vpadding' => 'auto',
    'hpadding' => 'auto',
    'fgcolor' => array(0,0,0),
    'bgcolor' => false, //array(255,255,255)
    'module_width' => 1, // width of a single module in points
    'module_height' => 1 // height of a single module in points
);

$pdf->write2DBarcode('www.tcpdf.org', 'QRCODE,H', 10, 10, 60, 60, $style, 'N');


$pdf->Output('test.PDF', 'D');
```

Result of size 60
https://prnt.sc/i8yva3

Result of size 500
https://prnt.sc/i8yvkt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$pdf = new FPDI('L', 'mm', array('119.888','50.038'));
$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
```

Add `SetAutoPageBreak` and set it to `false`. This will make sure that `style` works as expected.

```
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false); // important so styles don't break

$pdf->AddPage();
$page = $pdf->setSourceFile('aw_print.PDF');


$page = $pdf->ImportPage(1, 'TrimBox');
$pdf->useTemplate($page, 0, 0);


$x = 10;
$y = 10;

$style = array(
    'border' => 1,
    'vpadding' => 'auto',
    'hpadding' => 'auto',
    'fgcolor' => array(0,0,0),
    'bgcolor' => false, //array(255,255,255)
    'module_width' => 1, // width of a single module in points
    'module_height' => 1 // height of a single module in points
);
```

By default a barcode is confined to the page and margin size. 
Adding `true` for distort will enable you to scale to what ever size.

```
//    write2DBarcode($code, $type, $x, $y, $w, $h, $style, $align, $distort) {
$pdf->write2DBarcode('www.tcpdf.org', 'QRCODE,H', 10, 10, 60, 60, $style, 'N', true);


$pdf->Output('test.PDF', 'D');
```

Now that you are able to scale past the margins and page size `style` will not render properly unless you followed the first step and added `SetAutoPageBreak`.